# Set master page full screen on xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to make master page on MasterDetailPage of Xamarin.Forms full width?
Without leaving the margin (little view of detail) on the right

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, You cannot do that

Comment: :-( Thanks though.. It could be great doing so

Comment: Delete the question if this answered you!

Comment: I'm gonna wait a bit, maybe somebody knows a way...

Comment: You can use `ScrollView`  . And customize the TitleView of ContentPage (without using Master-Detail-Page).

Comment: Without using MasterDetailPage, you can customize a Content Page which looks like a MasterDetailPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not the proper way its a simple hack if you dont find any solution u can use this what i did to my MasterDetailsPage is

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SendwichApp.Views.MainPage"
             MasterBehavior="Popover"
             IsPresented="{Binding IsPresentedCustom, Mode=TwoWay}"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SendwichApp.Views"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:MycontentPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

something like this i have set `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` on my content page as well and created a custom navigation bar on which menu click i have set

Ispresented="True"
i have created message Center to display Side menu

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>("OpenMenu", "OpenMenu",
                    (sender) => viewModel.IsPresentedCustom = true);
```

and when i need to display side menu from any other page i just set `ispresented=true` by calling

```
 MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "OpenMenu");
```